# How to animate a Slider in SwiftUI smoothly like how WhatsApp/Apple Music does?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a slider for my music app that updates its knob position every second using a Timer publisher. But I don't want it to pause animating after each second instead animate smoothly and continuously like the slider/scrubber from WhatsApp Media View or Apple Music. Here is the code that I tried:

[This is what WhatsApp does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vos1L.gif)

[This is what my app does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb3OD.gif)

```
//My View Model
class AudioPlaybackManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {        
    var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, tolerance: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @Published var sliderValue = 0.0 
    
}

//My View
struct Scrubber: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var audioPlaybackManager: AudioPlaybackManager
        
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $audioPlaybackManager.sliderValue, in: 0...audioPlaybackManager.duration) { _ in
            audioPlaybackManager.audioPlayer?.currentTime = audioPlaybackManager.sliderValue
        }
        .onReceive(audioPlaybackManager.timer) { _ in
           //Right here, I want the slider to move/animate continuously instead of animate for each second and pause for a while.
            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                if audioPlaybackManager.isPlaying {
                    audioPlaybackManager.sliderValue = audioPlaybackManager.audioPlayer?.currentTime ?? 0.0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you're seeing the behavior you are because you're using the `.easeInOut` `Animation`, which does not apply the animation at a constant speed, but instead starts slowly, speeds up and ends slowly - easing in and out. I think if you change to use `.linear` instead, it will fix your behavior because the animation will be applied evenly over time instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, Im getting the exact same behaviour as the previous one. I think the animation is only applied during each second and doesn't animate between each second - if you know what I mean. Not sure what's the solution for this.

Comment: hmm, so because this only updates when your timer fires, maybe you need to make that timer fire more often (assuming that fires every second today) to smooth out the updates?

Comment: Timers are CPU hogs. Increasing the frequency to for example, 0.1 second takes 33% of cpu which is nuts. Struggling to find a solution.

Comment: I wonder if you're able to use the `duration` parameter of the `.linear` `Animation` to have the animation take place over the same timeframe as the timer update interval, therefore smoothing it out between updates.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/animation/linear(duration:)

Comment: This issue with that is the slider will always be 1 second behind. Frankly, this sounds like a job for a Combine publisher and publish the `audioPlaybackManager.audioPlayer?.currentTime` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Yrb. But how do I publish my currentTime of my AVAudioPlayer if I can't use its properties during initialisation of my class (View model)? And how do I keep sending updates from AVAudioPlayer's currentTime property to @Published property.

Comment: If that puts the slider 1 second behind, a super naive answer would be to animate the `sliderValue` to `currentTime+1`